# Как выполнить системную команду Линукс с параметром пользователя на c++?

Tags: c++, linux, c, консоль, командная-строка

Вообщем, мне нужно написать код который создаст папку с названием, который задаст пользователь, но, при запуске программы просто ничего не происходит.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string name;
    cout<<"Name of directory\n>";
    cin>>name;
    system("mkdir " + 'name');
    return 0;
}
```

В данном случаи программа получает название папки и она должна создать её, но... Как Вы поняли ничего не происходит. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: а почему не использовать `filesystem` для таких задач вместо вызовов `system`?

Comment: да, и почему вы игнорируете предупереждения компилятора?

Comment: посмотрите внимательно на эту строку `system("mkdir " + 'name');` и подумайте, что она делает и что должна

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
system(("mkdir " + name).c_str());
```

Или вообще без консольных команд:

```
std::filesystem::create_directory(name);
```

Comment: Получилось, спасибо!